# Get the names of the validators with errors in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a JSON API using Rails. Because the client is responsible for rendering error messages, I'd like to replace the default error messages with the name of the validator. For example, instead of `contact.errors.to_hash` returning this:

```
{
  :name=>["can't be blank"], 
  :email=>["can't be blank", "is invalid"], 
  :message=>["can't be blank"]
}
```

I'd like for it to return this:

```
{
  :name=>["presence"], 
  :email=>["presence", "format"], 
  :message=>["presence"]
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Rails?

**Edit:**

I discovered error messages have predefined types that are documented in the [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation). For example, `presence` is mapped to `blank`. I don't mind if these mapped values are used.

Answer (score 0):

[**Custom Validators**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations)

Apart from just changing the `:message` attribute to be the name of the problem, you may wish to use a [Custom Validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations) to build the errors hash manually:

```
#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    validates_with MyValidator
end

class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
    def validate(record)
        unless your_logic_here
           record.errors[:name] << ['Need a name starting with X please!', 'presence']
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm really just looking to use the built in validators.

Comment: Okay! The [errors hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) doesn't look like it has the actual format of the error. I could be wrong, but I felt the custom validator would allow you to add to the errors hash in your own way

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it doesn't. There's an internal error class used by `ActiveModel::Errors` that has a `type` attribute, but it isn't exposed. A custom validator would allow me to add my own message, but it feels like more work than it's worth. I posted my ugly solution to the problem.

Comment: Congrats on getting something working! I'll have another think about what you could do to improve it

Comment: Thanks! Let me know if you come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty solution was to override the error messages in the i18n en.yml file with the name of the type.

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      blank: "blank"
      invalid: "invalid"
```

This works, but it feels dirty and unnecessary. I'm hoping somebody else will come up with a better solution.